# A shortcut way to write x = x * (1 + Markup)

Tags: c#, .net

We're writing an app that deals with product pricing.  As you might imagine, there are many uses of what amounts to `Price = Price * (1 + MarkupPercent);` throughout the code.

I went hunting for an operator, perhaps similar to `+=`, that would make things easier to not only write, but read.  No luck, at least as far as I can tell.  Since `Price` and `MarkupPercent` are both of type `float`, I started thinking of extending `float` to add `Markup(float Percent)`.

This seems feasible, but I'd rather use a more standard (i.e. included in the framework) way than start making random extensions to base classes.  Suggestions?

Comment: You can use `*=`: `Price *= (1 + MarkupPercent);`

Comment: That's at least a little better.

Comment: @CalebB Looks like an answer to me :)

Comment: Side note: I hope that you are aware of the limited precision of the `float` data type. Normally it's never used for repesenting monetary values.

Comment: I'm not aware.  What type better represents monetary values?

Comment: Decimal.. Also, if you're using one code over and over, wouldn't be better to create a property with only a getter specified? Or a method, whatever makes sense? Like this it looks like violating DRY principle...

Comment: CodePlex has a `Money` class available for download.  I'm going to look into it and see if it helps our situation.  If not, I'll use Decimal.
https://csharpmoney.codeplex.com/

Comment: @J.D.Ray: The precision of `float` only gives you six significant digits. A `double` gives you better precision, but you may still get rounding errors because it's a floating pont number. Usually `decimal` is used for monetary values, as it represents a number exactly.

Comment: @Guffa, erm, that word `exactly` isn't really true. But I agree it's the most suitable one...

Comment: @walther: In what way do you think that it isn't true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it would be to write an extension method for the `decimal` type, which would give you some added functionality:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static decimal GetMarkedUpPrice(this decimal basePrice, decimal percentMarkup)
    {
        return basePrice * (1 + percentMarkup);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public static void Main()
{
    decimal somePrice = 5.6m;
    decimal markedUpPrice = somePrice.GetMarkedUpPrice(.5m);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given all the above comments that answer the question, and that there's no actual answer contributed, I'm writing this.

The best-known effective way to deal with this is (essentially) as follows:

```
public Decimal Price { get; set; } // shorthanded here for brevity
public Decimal GetMarkedUpPrice(Decimal Percent)
{
    return Price * (1 + Percent);
}
```

OK, *"best known"* is probably hyperbolic.  This code captures the essence of the various comments, though.  Feel free to correct me if I've captured this wrong.

Alternately, just mark up the Price in place:

```
public Decimal Price { get; set; } // shorthanded here for brevity
public void MarkupThePrice(Decimal Percent)
{
    Price *= (1 + Percent);
}
```

Comment: I'd put parentheses around the `1 + Percent`.  It makes it more clear what the intent is.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives, to give you different ways to use the class:

```
public class Price
{
    // Instance properties
    public decimal BasePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal PercentMarkup { get; set; }
    public decimal MarkedupPrice { get { return GetMarkedUpPrice(PercentMarkup); } }

    // Instance method to allow you to show additional markup
    // prices without changing the instance property
    public decimal GetMarkedUpPrice(decimal percentMarkup)
    {
        return GetMarkedUpPrice(BasePrice, percentMarkup); 
    }

    // Static method to get a quick calculation without instance overhead
    public static decimal GetMarkedUpPrice(decimal basePrice, decimal percentMarkup)
    {
        return basePrice * (1 + percentMarkup);
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var hammerPrice = new Price {BasePrice = 10, PercentMarkup = .15m};

    Console.WriteLine("{0:C} hammers will be sold for {1:C}, except on " + 
        "Sunday, when they will be {2:C}", hammerPrice.BasePrice, 
        hammerPrice.MarkedupPrice, hammerPrice.GetMarkedUpPrice(.1m));

    Console.WriteLine("Otherwise, items with a base price of $10.00 " + 
        "will be sold for {0:C}", Price.GetMarkedUpPrice(10, .2m));
}
```